# React native export class and singleton method

Tags: react-native

I want to achieve something similar to how the Picker works in react native:

```js
<Picker>
  <Picker.Item />
</Picker>
```

But am unsure how I would export the class to achieve this.

I currently have the following which I thought would work but I get an undefined react element error:

```js
export default class extends React.Component {
  get Item () {
    return <Text>Foo</Text>;
  }

  render () {
    return <View></View>;
  }
}
```

> React.createElement: type should not be null, undefined, boolean or
>   number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the simplest way:

```js
class Picker extends React.Component {
  //...
}

class Item extends React.Component {
  //...
}

Picker.Item = Item;

export default Picker;
```